# How to include virtual ICollection and also specific item from this collection in EF core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, automapper, lazy-loading

I'm trying to load all properties of my Entity, but two of them are virtual. So I have to include them in query. The problem is that the second virtual property is single item from the first one.

Example: Let's suppose that I have Entity Magazine with all its Issues and CurrentIssue (from this moth). And I want to load everything.

```cs
public class Magazine
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Issue> Issues { get; set; }
    public virtual Issue CurrentIssueOn
    {
        get
        {
            if (Issues != null)
            {
                var date = DateTime.Now;

                if (date.AddDays(DaysSendBack) > DateTime.Now.Date)
                {
                    date = date.AddDays(DaysSendBack);
                }

                return Issues
                    .Where(i => (i.IssueDate.HasValue && i.IssueDate.Value >= date))
                    .OrderBy(i => i.IssueDate)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

And I have tried this:

```cs
public IQueryable<MagazineListViewModel> GetList(string userAuthToken)
{
    return mapper.ProjectTo<MagazineListViewModel>(dbContext
        .Magazine
        .Include(m => m.Issues)
        .Include(m => m.CurrentIssueOn)
        .AsNoTracking()
        .AsQueryable());
}
```

But the CurrentIssueOn is always null, because during query execution the Issues collection is still null.

I think, that if I remove the virtual keyword from Issues collection then It will work in this case. But I have another queries, where I dont want to include Issues, so its not good solution.

Comment: _"CurrentIssueOn is always null, because during query execution the Issues collection is still null"_ - that's not the cause. The CurrentIssueOn doesn't come from the database, do there's no need to Include() it. Put a breakpoint in your CurrentIssueOn getter, and see that it's your mapper calling it. There's probably an issue with your data or your logic in the getter.

Comment: You're right. Automapper calls the CurrentIssueOn getter. But if I put breakpoint inside it, then Issues collection is null despite ".Include(m => m.Issues)" in my query.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's going on here, but your entity should probably look like this:

```
public virtual ICollection<Issue> Issues { get } = new HashSet<Issue>();
[NotMapped]
public virtual Issue CurrentIssueOn
{
```

There's no reason to start with your Navigation Property collections being `null`.  Just initialize them to empty collections.